# Not able to access the external resource through glassfish when using alternatedocroot

Tags: java, web-applications, resources, glassfish

The application I'm working on is deployed in Glassfish v3.1.1. I'm trying to use alternate document root to serve files from outside the war.

This is the content i have specified in glassfish-web.xml

`<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>xyz</context-root>
    <property name="alternatedocroot_2" value="from=/new/\* dir=E:/xyz"/>
    </glassfish-web-app>`

The static files are stored in this location:

```
E:\xyz\new
```

After deployment,when the file is accessed using this url,I get a 404 response.

```
http://localhost:8080/xyz/new/1_RD_2.png
```

I did a search on how the requests are matched, and the above code seems to match with what was given [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jluehe/entry/alternate_docroots_and_local_resource).
But still, the code doesn't work. Is there something i'm missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above mentioned configurations were correct. The code dint work due to a conflicting url pattern mentioned in the web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>JerseyTest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After changing the above pattern in web.xml to

```
<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
```

the static files were accessible.